# Laravel 4.0 PHP web app, moving from production to develpoment environment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

My web application is up and running on production. But I lost my development sources due to laptop got formatted. Can I recreate my development environment from production environment?

I tried following steps but no success:

- Installed Laravel 4.0 server.
- Copied public html folder content.
- ran composer
- copied `/app/config/` to `/app/config/local/`
- modified `/bootstrap/start.php` to local host name.

But still when start my local server it is not able to map path of files correctly.

Comment: When you copy your whole Laravel production environment to your local web server (homestead or whatever you prefer) that should be all to be done. Maybe you will have to fix some config due to database connection or something. That depends on your app.

Comment: Any errors in the log ?

Answer (score 0):

**If your development and production server is same version** then you should just change the url, database credentials etc.,

**If the versions are different versions** then you should place the views, controllers, then in the controller you should require all the stuffs that you need

I believe you should have same versions of laravel in production and development.

So, you should probably change only the db credentials.

**Note :** Clear the views and sessions in the storage after you change the credentials

**Advice :**

### Please use SVN to avoid such happenings in future